# How to upload image to Google using Laravel 4?

Tags: php, image, laravel-4, upload

I want to upload images in Google and get this link. I am using Laravel 4.2.

Comment: Where exactly "in google" do you want to upload the image?

Comment: We encourage people here to show what they have tried, and often point out that if a Stack Overflow question is one or two sentences long, it's probably off-topic. Please give it a go first, and let us know if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having your own website that has it's own content -> images too, then you need to have a robot.txt file, in that file, you need to "allow robots" to view your site.

After that your images will be "uploaded" to google.

Tip: Add [tags](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_alt.asp) to your images